# 5 columns, 2 colums are margin-top: height

Tags: html, css

I got 5 columns in a container and i want 2 margin-top: 50p; with the other 3 still staying top. Instead of following the others.

```css
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.column {
    width: 19%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #039BE5;
}

.margin {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column margin"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column margin"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, inline elements are vertically aligned on the baseline. Just change the vertical alignment for your columns to text-top.

```
.column {
    width: 19%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #039BE5;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```